# Integrate Legendre polynomials in SymPy and use these integrals as coefficients

Tags: sympy

I am trying to make a simple example in SymPy to compute some coefficients and then use them in a sum of legendre polynomials. Finally plot it. Very simple but can not make it work. I want to use it for my electromagnetism course. I get errors in both the attempts below:

```
%matplotlib inline
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
f, step, potential = symbols('f step potential', cls=Function)
var('n x')
A=SeqFormula(2*(2*m+1)*Integral(legendre(2*m+1,x),(x,0,1)).doit(),(m,0,oo)).doit()
Sum(A.coeff(m).doit()*legendre(2*m+1,x),(m,0,10)).doit()
B=Tuple.fromiter(2*(2*n+1)*Integral(legendre(2*n+1,x),(x,0,1)).doit() for n in range(50))
Sum(B[m]*legendre(2*m+1,x),(m,0,10)).doit()
```

Here is a part of an script in Mathematica of what I would like to replicate:

```
Nn = 50; 
Array[A, Nn] 
For[i = 0, i <= Nn, i++, A[i + 1] = Integrate[LegendreP[2*i + 1, x]*(2*(2*i + 1) + 1), {x, 0, 1}]]; 
Step = Sum[A[n + 1]*LegendreP[2*n + 1, #], {n, 0, Nn}] & Plot[Step[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Here is a part of an script in Mathematica of what I would like to replicate:                                                             
      Nn = 50;
      Array[A, Nn]
      For[i = 0, i <= Nn, i++,
      A[i + 1] = Integrate[LegendreP[2*i + 1, x]*(2*(2*i + 1) + 1), {x, 0, 1}]];                                                                                                        
      Step = Sum[A[n + 1]*LegendreP[2*n + 1, #], {n, 0, Nn}] &
      Plot[Step[x], {x, -1, 1}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the structure you were searching for with A is Python's lambda.

```
A = lambda m: 2*(2*m+1)*Integral(legendre(2*m+1, x), (x, 0, 1))
f = Sum(A(m)*legendre(2*m+1, x), (m, 0, 10)).doit()
plot(f, (x, -1, 1))
```

The key point is that m has to be explicit in order for integration to happen; SymPy does not know a general formula for integrating `legendre(n, x)`. So, the integration here is attempted only when `A` is called with a concrete value of m, like `A(0)`, `A(1)`, etc.

[image: graph]